# How to replace a BackGround Image in Login Screen?

Tags: odoo

i need some help,do you know how to change the background image's login of odoov8?i've already developed a theme custom module and i've tried to replace the image; this is code :

```
<template id="login_layout" name="My Theme Login" inherit_id="web.login_layout">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_single_form_footer']" position="replace">
        <div class="oe_single_form_footer">Powered by T</div><!-- it works-->
    </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_single_form']" position="replace">
        <div class="oe_single_form"><img src="/static/src/img/logo.png'" alt="My Theme Logo"  title="My Theme Logo" /></div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

but the error I get is:

```
Element '&lt;xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_single_form']">' cannot be located in parent view
```

and its so logic cause in the inherit template unlike the "oe_single_form_footer" the "oe_single_form" its not in a div balise(sorry am new with odoo):

```
<template id="web.login_layout" name="Login Layout">
    <t t-call="web.layout">
        <t t-set="head">
            <link href="/web/static/src/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="/web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </t>
        <t t-set="body_classname" t-value="'oe_single_form'"/>
        <div class="oe_single_form_container modal-content">
            <div class="oe_single_form_logo">
                <img t-attf-src="/web/binary/company_logo{{ '?dbname='+db if db else '' }}"/>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <t t-raw="0"/>
            <div class="oe_single_form_footer" t-if="not disable_footer">
                <t t-if="not disable_database_manager">
                    <a class="oe_login_manage_db" t-attf-href="/web/database/manager{{ '?debug' if debug else '' }}">Manage Databases</a>
                    <span class="oe_footer_seperator"> | </span>
                </t>
                <a href="https://www.odoo.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>Odoo</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You instructed Odoo to find and replace a div with class "oe_single_form", but no such div exists. It seems to me you wanted to replace "oe_single_form_logo":

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_single_form_logo']" position="replace">
    <div class="oe_single_form_logo"><img src="/static/src/img/logo.png'" alt="My Theme Logo"  title="My Theme Logo" /></div>
</xpath>
```